# Solution explorer files are being ignored and not compiling

Tags: git, visual-studio

I have added existing files to my solution explorer in Visual Studio but they have a little red icon next to them that says 'ignored'.

These files do not get compiled when I create a new build.

How do I stop Visual Studio from ignoring these files?

[image: ignored]

Comment: You should have either a `.npmignore` or some other vs ignore file where they appear, check if you can find that.

Comment: In the solution repository? there is no such file or any file containing 'ignore'

Comment: are you sure you see all the files (hidden ones as well), if not there is a configuration somewhere that is preventing this from being compiled, I cant say that I am familiar with solution explorer

Comment: Yes the hidden files checkbox is checked. Thanks anyway